# CGAL Python bindings with Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, cgal

Has anyone succeeded in installing the CGAL python bindings in the anaconda environment?  I have successfully installed them onto my system (Mac OSX ElCapitan) but they only work for /usr/bin/python and not my anaconda python.  I've tried messing with the CMake files to no avail.  I've changed the python paths to point to anaconda python and also the changed the swig paths to point to anaconda swig which I installed using conda.   No luck!

On that note, it would be wonderful to be able to type conda install cgal :)

Thanks for your help.

Adrian

Comment: Try modifying in your `CMakeCache.txt` `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`,
`PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` and `PYTHON_LIBRARY`

Comment: I've made the following modifications.                                                      //Path to a program.
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/butscher/anaconda/bin/python2.7
//Path to a file.
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/Users/butscher/anaconda/include/python2.7
//Path to a library.
PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/Users/butscher/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib

Comment: But the above does not work. To be precise, when I make the changes listed above, neither /usr/bib/python nor /Users/butscher/anaconda/bin/python is able to run the CGAL test script. The latter continues to say "Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_get: no current thread Abort trap: 6".  The former yields this error message:

Comment: File ".../CGAL_Triangulation_3.py", line 28, in <module>
    _CGAL_Triangulation_3 = swig_import_helper()
  File ".../CGAL_Triangulation_3.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_CGAL_Triangulation_3', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(.../_CGAL_Triangulation_3.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpython2.7.dylib
  Referenced from: .../_CGAL_Triangulation_3.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libpython2.7.dylib in .../_CGAL_Triangulation_3.so with restricted binary

Comment: where ... above is /Users/butscher/Desktop/cgal-swig-bindings-master/build-python/CGAL

Comment: so compilation went fine? If yes, check that the lib generated are only linked with python libs from anaconda.

Comment: Yes, the libraries compile. My apologies for the elementary question -- how do I check that the lib generated are only linked with python libs from anaconda?  Thanks.

Comment: Presumably the answer is that something is linked to a library in the wrong place... So I'd have to figure out which library is the culprit.

Comment: call `ldd` on the `_CGAL_XXXX.so` generated. You should have a libpython in the list of libs.

Comment: OK...  The original install gives me:

Comment: _CGAL_AABB_tree.so:
 /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
 /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
 /usr/local/opt/cgal/lib/libCGAL.11.dylib
 /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
 /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
 /Users/butscher/Desktop/cgal-swig-bindings-master/lib/libCGAL_AABB_tree_cpp.dylib
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python 
 /Users/butscher/Desktop/cgal-swig-bindings-master/lib/libCGAL_Kernel_cpp.dylib
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: If I make the changes to CMakeCache.txt as in the comment above, I now get the same as above EXCEPT for the line "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python" which becomes simply libpython2.7.dylib.   [Sorry, these comments must be hard to read...]